# correct way to find the result of modulo

Tags: java, modulo, number-theory

As We all know, [modulo operation finds the remainder of division of one number by another](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

I'm strruggling to figure out the correct way to get value of modulo.

a mod b = c

It's easy to find c if a >= 0. But, if a < 0, it's confusing me.

One day, I read in my lecturer notes if -75 mod 26 = 3.

Then, I create a simple program in java to find the result of -75 mod 26. The program compiles and prints result: -23.

So, what is the right way to find c if a < 0?

Belows is code I've tried:

```
public class modulo {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        int divide = -75;  

        int val = divide % 26; 

        System.out.println(divide+" % 26 = "+ val);

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you not just do mod abs(number) and then re make it negative

Comment: @Jeef: Nope, that would also give -23.

Comment: `int val = divide % 26; if (val < 0) val += 26;`

Answer (score 0):

Why won't you get absolute value from both before division?

```
public class modulo {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        int divide = -75;  
        int val = Math.abs(divide) % Math.abs(26); 
        System.out.println(divide+" % 26 = "+ val);
    }
}
```

...or simply get abs value from the result (with rounding)?

```
Math.round( result );
```

Comment: Simply rounding the result will yield wrong result.

Comment: I just proposed the solution. For proper rounding he can search for proper implementation (or write his own)

Comment: What I'm saying is that `abs(a % b) != abs(a) % abs(b)`. The latter is mathematically correct but the former isn't.